# Why is nohup required and disown doesn't work by itself?

Tags: bash, signals, nohup

Consider this snippet as being saved in a file called `snippet.sh`:

```
nohup xmessage HI </dev/null &>/dev/null & disown
sleep 3
```

From the same directory, do `xterm -e bash snippet.sh`.

After 3 seconds, the `xterm` should disappear while the `xmessage` window lingers. All good and well. But what if the `nohup` is removed from the command in the snippet file? Then the `xmessage` which disappears along with the `xterm`. The `bash` documentation seems to indicate that `disown` should, by itself, be sufficient to prevent `SIGHUP` from being sent:

```
       The  shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP.  Before exiting, an interactive shell resends
       the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent  SIGCONT  to  ensure  that  they
       receive the SIGHUP.  To prevent the shell from sending the signal to a particular job, it should be
       removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below) or marked to
       not receive SIGHUP using disown -h.
```

So, the question is, why won't the `xmessage` window linger without `nohup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disown` is sufficient to prevent the *shell* from sending the signal, but it doesn't stop anyone else.

In particular, the shell is the controlling process of the terminal with `xmessage` in its process group, and [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01) that on exit:

> If the process is a controlling process, the SIGHUP signal shall be sent to each process in the foreground process group of the controlling terminal belonging to the calling process.